# understand the output of bsdlabel

Tags: partition, freebsd

I have a [Juniper](http://juniper.net) router which uses Junos(based on FreeBSD) operating system where I can backup certain partitions from router CLI. Under the hood router starts the `restore` process and copies `/dev/ad0s1a` to `/dev/ad1s1a` and `/dev/ad0s1e` to `/dev/ad1s1e`. FreeBSD partitions before this copy operation are following:

```
# bsdlabel /dev/ad0s1
# /dev/ad0s1:
8 partitions:
#        size   offset    fstype   [fsize bsize bps/cpg]
  a:   451556        0    4.2BSD     2048 16384 28224 
  c:   501728        0    unused        0     0         # "raw" part, don't edit
  e:    50172   451556    4.2BSD     2048 16384  3136 
# bsdlabel /dev/ad1s1
# /dev/ad1s1:
8 partitions:
#        size   offset    fstype   [fsize bsize bps/cpg]
  a:   451556        0    4.2BSD     2048 16384    96 
  b:  4194288   451556      swap                    
  c: 58605057        0    unused        0     0         # "raw" part, don't edit
  e:    50172  4645844    4.2BSD     2048 16384   105 
  f: 53909041  4696016    4.2BSD     2048 16384    89 
#
```

After the copy operation they are following:

```
# bsdlabel /dev/ad0s1
# /dev/ad0s1:
8 partitions:
#        size   offset    fstype   [fsize bsize bps/cpg]
  a:   451556        0    4.2BSD     2048 16384 28224 
  c:   501728        0    unused        0     0         # "raw" part, don't edit
  e:    50172   451556    4.2BSD     2048 16384  3136 
# bsdlabel /dev/ad1s1
# /dev/ad1s1:
8 partitions:
#        size   offset    fstype   [fsize bsize bps/cpg]
  a:   451556        0    4.2BSD     2048 16384 28224 
  b:  4194288   451556      swap                    
  c: 58605057        0    unused        0     0         # "raw" part, don't edit
  e:    50172  4645844    4.2BSD     2048 16384  3136 
  f: 53909041  4696016    4.2BSD     2048 16384    89 
#
```

As seen from the output of `bsdlabel` before and after the copy operation, the `bps/cpg` counter increased after coping for `/dev/ad1s1a` and `/dev/ad1s1e` partitions. Am I correct that before the copy operation the `/dev/ad1s1a` and `/dev/ad1s1e` partitions were present, but they were almost empty? So probably this copy operation mirrored the whole file-system from `/dev/ad0s1a` to `/dev/ad1s1a` and `/dev/ad0s1e` to `/dev/ad1s1e`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I believe you are correct. Though `bsdlabel` gives information about the partitions, it also gives some information about the file system in the partition in the `bps/cpg` column. See the [bsdlabel man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bsdlabel&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) for more information. The `restore` command is probably receiving data from the `dump` command. See the [restore man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=restore&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) and the [dump man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dump&sektion=8&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.2-RELEASE) for more details.